# Organize 3d array equivivalent in sql table

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql

In my C# program I am parsing a website and I want to count the most frequent sequences of two or three elements.

Lets say I have 10 variants.

It can be `1-2-2`, `4-5-1` etc. `1-3-4` == `3-1-4`

Right now I'm thinking about array of int (`[,,]`), but I want to store and analyse information, so I decided to create a PostgreSQL DB.

Now I'm thinking about the best and easiest way to organize a 3d array equivalent via a sql table, can you suggest me something?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: An array won't work if [1,3,4] is the same as [3,1,4].  Also, if the range of numbers is large an array would consume insane memory.  It sounds like you need to do something like take the sequence, sort the numbers, convert to to a string by putting a dash in between like in your examples.  Then that is the key to a hashtable or to your database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A table with four columns can be used to hold the same data a 3D array can hold. The first three columns can be the array indices (say x,y and z), and the fourth column can hold the data value; Data[x,y,z].

Comment: Using this model, how would you handle the situation where the same index values appear in a different order? (note that the OP stated that 1-3-4 == 3-1-4)

Comment: True, and a valid point. My answer only offered some humble insight into the question concerning ... "the best and easiest way to organize a 3d array equivalent via a sql table". A table with four columns certainly does that. That said, I'm not really sure a 3D array would be my data structure of choice for solving a sequence counting problem like this.

Comment: well, i'll wait a bit more, maybe someone offer me less synthetic way to solve the problem with SQL, but i guess your variant will be the answer. If my math is right i will need 10^3 rows to implement all of the indexes (and in reality i have >100 variants), so maybe i need to think more about how to store and analyse sequences better.

Comment: @s1ddok - by "variants", do you mean the numbers in your sequences? Like 1, 3, 4, etc?