# Alternative method to save data than my.settings for VB.Net

Tags: database, vb.net

I need to save approximately *1600 different pieces of information* for a windows forms application.

What is the best way to go about this? For example some of the user settings would look like this `measuringItem1Name`, `measuringItem1Equation`, `measuringItem1Enabled`, `measuringItem1Offset`, `measuringItem2Name`...

I have looked into my.settings, however, I found that it would be very tedious and error prone to type out every user setting.

It seems like the best solution would be to have a type of table that can access each individual cell and edit that information.

Does something like this exist? If so, how would it be implemented with *VB.Net*?

Comment: Is this a multy users application? if so, should the values set by one user be visible to another user? Is this a website, winforms, wpf application?

Comment: Consider [serialization](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25880148/1070452)

Comment: @ZoharPeled This is a windows forms application. Typically there will only be one user, but the ability for other users to use the same settings would be a bonus.

Comment: I see in your post `measuringItem1Name`... `measuringItem2Name...`. I'm guessing that you have a limited number of data points for each measuringItem but a lot of measuringItems to deal with, correct?

Comment: @ZoharPeled that is more or less correct. There will be 16 different potential measuring items. Each item will have various settings that are used to calculate them including which sensors will be used, individual equations, names, etc. The actual measurements will be stored elsewhere. I just need a good method for storing the user settings.

Comment: Well, since Bradley Uffner already gave you a code example on how to use serialization for that, I would probably go with this option, unless your application already is working with a database that holds other information that is related to measuring Items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend creating a class with properties to hold your settings.  Mark the class as serializable.  Then serialize and deserialize an instance of this class as application startup / shutdown to the user's profile directory.  This will allow you to have strongly typed settings that save separately per user if you ever need that option.  It will also allow you to easily set default values for the settings.

You can make the "settings" class as deep as you want, with properties made up of other sub setting classes or lists of settings by index.  It's a very powerful pattern.

For example:

```
settings.MeasuringItem(1).Enabled = True
settings.MeasuringItem(1).Equation = "1+1"
settings.MeasuringItem(1).Offset = 15

settings.MeasuringItem(2).Enabled = True
settings.MeasuringItem(2).Equation = "1+1"
settings.MeasuringItem(2).Offset = 15
```

`Settings` is the main settings class with a `Generic.List(of MeasuringItem)` property on it.  `MeasuingItem` is another class with `.Enabled As Boolean`, `.Equation as string` , etc properties on it.

I haven't really checked this for errors.  You will want to do a lot more safety checking, but this should get you started.

```
<Serializable>
Public Class Settings

    Public Sub New()
        _measuringItems = New List(Of MeasuringItem)
    End Sub

    Private _measuringItems As List(Of MeasuringItem)
    Public ReadOnly Property MeasuringItems As List(Of MeasuringItem)
        Get
            Return _measuringItems
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Sub Save()
        Using s As New IO.FileStream("Path to save", IO.FileMode.Create)

            Dim formatter As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
            formatter.Serialize(s, Me)
        End Using
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function Load() As Settings
        Dim settings As Settings = Nothing

        Using s As New IO.FileStream("Path to load", IO.FileMode.Open)

            Dim formatter As New System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter
            settings = CType(formatter.Deserialize(s), ServerHost.Settings)
        End Using
        Return settings
    End Function


End Class

<Serializable>
Public Class MeasuringItem
    Public Property Enabled As Boolean = True 'These are the default values
    Public Property Equation As String = "1+1"
    Public Property Offset As Integer = 15
End Class
```

A quick example of usage:

```
    'Create a completely new settings instance with 100 measuring items
    Dim settings1 As Settings = New Settings
    For i As Integer = 1 To 100
        settings1.MeasuringItems.Add(New MeasuringItem)
    Next
    settings1.MeasuringItems(0).Enabled = False
    settings1.MeasuringItems(5).Equation = "testing"

    'Save it
    settings1.Save()

    'load the saved settings
    Dim settings2 As Settings = Settings.Load
```

Comment: Could you provide sample code as to how this could be implemented for a simple case?

Comment: Sure, give me a few minutes.

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe I'm too much of a noob. I'm having trouble initializing the class and actually saving changes to the class. What code do you need to call to do this?

Comment: added some sample usage

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a database to store the values in.  I don't know your operating environment (for example, I have several enterprise SQL servers available for my use.)  You could go with  [SQL Express Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx), which is free.  [SQL Lite](http://www.sqlite.org/) is an option as well.  You could even use Access, but that requires MS Office be installed.

If you don't want to go the database route, you can create a settings class, and make the class serializable .  This will serialize the object to either a binary file or a XML file (depending on how you set it up.)  If you want to go this approach, I'll post the code for you.

Comment: If i were to use Sql Server Express, would my install file have to also include Sql Server? I'm sorry, I have never used a database.

Comment: If you are distributing the software, you would have to distribute that software as well.  I do not know if the license of SQL Express would let you bundle it with an installer, but I suspect SQL Lite would.

Comment: Is it possible to make a 3D Table using SQL Express or SQL Lite?

Comment: By 3D, if you are referring storing a multidimensional data (i.e. stored as an array) in the database,  then yes.  There are several techniques that you can leverage, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25271827/organize-3d-array-equivivalent-in-sql-table.  If you're talking about another data-storage type, then I am not sure.

Comment: If you are dealing with thousands of variables to be saved, I'd be tempted to create a table that lists all of those variables, and another table of data, and link them.  This makes your design flexible and easier to add and remove configuration data.  You can then build a form to modify the values.