# vb.net datetimepicker not taking value from my.setting

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I have this code to save value from `datetimepicker1`:

```
Private Sub DateTimePicker1_Validating(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
     Handles DateTimePicker1.Validating
                        My.Settings.dt1value= DateTimePicker1.Value.ToString
                        MsgBox("before save")
                        My.Settings.Save()
                        MsgBox("after save")
End Sub
```

It look that it saves value in `My.Settings` (From Message box 1,2)

Then when closing the app and running it again; it is not loading the `My.Settings.dt1value` into `DateTimePicker1`

The code for loading is:

```
Private Sub main_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
            DateTimePicker1.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(My.Settings.dt1value)
End Sub
```

Other controls like `Textbox1` is saving and loading properly but only for `DateTimePicker` is not working.

I tried to change from `Handles Me.Shown` to `Handles Me.Load` but same problem.

**I have another problem**,

When I deploy the application and setup in windows, `My.Setting.Save()` not working for all controls.

I had read other similar posts and try to follow them but nothing helps.

Any tip appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe change the type of your setting to Date instead of string.  Then save `My.Settings.dt1value = DatePicker1.Value`

Comment: Thank you @TheWhiteWolf, but that didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check whether the value is getting saved. Use

```
MsgBox(My.Settings.dt1value)
```

instead of

```
MsgBox("after save").
```

This will ensure the value is getting saved.

> MsgBox("before save") & MsgBox("after save") does NOTHING useful here

But as from your code snippet, It seems the value is getting saved.
In the form `Load` event write the below mentioned code and check for the output:

```
string DatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"; 
DateTime ConvertedDateTime; 
DateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.TryParseExact(My.Settings.dt1value, DatePattern , null, DateTimeStyles.None, out ConvertedDateTime))
```

Edit : About your second problem

That is because whenever you update or modify the application in any way, the My.Settings(built-in settings file) gets flushed and a new one is generated. I would suggest you to save your config file in a separate external file. NOT in My.Settings

Comment: Thank you @nobody , the problem was something else not expected. Still facing the second problem.

Comment: That is because whenever you `update` or `modify` the application in any way, the `My.Settings`(built-in settings file) gets flushed and a new one is generated. I would suggest you to save your config file in a separate external file. NOT in `My.Settings`

Comment: I've updated my answer. Click the tick on the left to mark it as answer :)

Comment: Thank you @nobody, I found this post based on your answer https://stackoverflow.com/q/29634895/7735285 , did solve my **2nd issue**, thanks alot